# GPU rendering no light penetration in large scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

When i am rendering in cycles large scene (not really, 470k verts) in GPU mode there is no light penetration through holes and glass, even if i render with 10 samples. In small scene (<80k verts) all is ok. In CPU rendering also all is ok, but it's not funny when you render one frame for 2 hours.
Radeon 7970 (OpenCL).
Is there any solution for this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image showing the problem?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAgKeYWcdbZWAl Sorry for this noise

Comment: Hm. Is it possible you could upload a .blend demonstrating this behavior? It's possible this is a bug..

Comment: .blend is too large. For example, I copy all objects from the scene and then put into another - result is the same. Then i delete 80% of objects - all lights and shadows rendered good

Comment: @ne1s At least that suggests that some stray object is causing this. Perhaps the window object has a transparent shader? It appears [openCL doesn't yet support *transparent shadows*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html), which is an optimization which vastly improves sampling lamps which cast light through partially transparent objects. What happens if you try a mesh light outside the window? If that appears to be the cause of the issue, it shouldn't be too hard to rig up a workaround using renderlayers.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

check the progressive refine box in render panel.

Answer (score -2):

Same problem on *NVIDEA Quadro K4200*.
Progressive refine didnt solved the problem. 
Enabeling `Refracive Caustics` dit solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't use answer function for your comments

Comment: Oh, i tohught of it as anoter solution alternative that might works for some people. Does this edit help?